# How to import a package into DartPad?

Tags: flutter, dartpad

I'm doing Codelabs [Write your first Flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1#3). Step 4 is about using external packages. Is it possible to import external packages into DartPad? I see tabs in the lower left for "Console" and "Documentation" but there's nothing in these panes. Is the console a future feature of DartPad? Is there another way to import external packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all packages that are listed under

> Directly importable packages

(The dialog you see in the screenshot opens by clicking on the info icon on the bottom right corner)

[image: Directly imported packages]

you can simply import them by adding the respective import statement to the top of your DartPad code. Here's an example for `GoogleFonts`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// simply add this line to import GoogleFonts
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'This is Google Fonts',
      // Use the package wherever you like
      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, letterSpacing: .5),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```